# Should I use nested routes on a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Beginner question sorry. I have 3 tables in a test app, "Deals", "Investors" and "Opportunities". Opportunity is the join.

An Opportunity `belongs_to` Deal and Investor, while deals and investors both has_many opportunities.

I want to be able to do things like view all opportunities within the scope of a deal or an investor, but also to list all opportunities in the application. How do I set up routes for that? Something like the below?

```
  resources :deals do
    resources :opportunities
  end 
  resources :investors do
    resources :opportunities
  end
  resources :opportunities
```

Comment: Try running `rake routes` from the command line and look at the output. This will give you a good idea of what to expect if you visited those pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would make sense if you wanted to show the opportunities on their own page, using the same behavior as you do for the normal opportunities page (since they're likely to be handled by the same controller / views). In that case, the nested `:opportunities` are probably read-only (opportunities would be updated via their top-level route), so you might want to do `resources :opportunities, only: :index`.

However, in my experience, nested resources like `opportunities` are more likely to be shown directly on the page of a given deal or investor. In that case you wouldn't need those nested `resource :opportunities` routes at all. You would simply load `@deal` on the `show` action of DealsController and make use of `@deal.opportunities` in the show page template to print the opportunities.